# Count and compare elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

`playerArray` has seven elements. I want to return true if  whatever array is passed into hasEnoughPlayers is at least 7 and false if it isn't.

I tried using `playerArray.length - 1`. Still doesn't work.

```
var hasEnoughPlayers = function(playerArray){
    for (var i = 0; i < (playerArray.length - 1); i++){
        if ((playerArray.length - 1) == 7){
           return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;

        }
    }
};
```

I keep getting a false or some error message.
Here is the code tested with a `team` array.

```
var hasEnoughPlayers = function(playerArray){
            return playerArray.length  === 7;
};

var team = ["Oliver Wood", "Angelina Johnson", "Katie Bell", "Alicia Spinnet", "George Weasley", "Fred Weasley", "Harry Potter"];
console.log(hasEnoughPlayers(team));
```

Comment: What is `player`?

Comment: Why not `function(playerArray){ return playerArray.length === 7 }` Why do you need a loop?

Comment: Why do you think you need a loop? And why are you subtracting 1 from the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop at all if I am understanding the question correctly. You can simply check the length

```
var hasEnoughPlayers = function(playerArray){
    return playerArray.length >= 7
}
```

Here is a full working example...

```js
var hasEnoughPlayers = function(playerArray){
  return playerArray.length  === 7;
};

var team = [
  "Oliver Wood", 
  "Angelina Johnson", 
  "Katie Bell", 
  "Alicia Spinnet", 
  "George Weasley", 
  "Fred Weasley", 
  "Harry Potter"
];

alert(hasEnoughPlayers(team));
```

Comment: Thanks. How do test for ```false```?

Comment: `if ( ! hasEnoughPlayers( players ) ) { // do stuff here if there were not enough players }`

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error: ```- Cannot read property 'params' of undefined```

Comment: @EmmanuelAni I don't see anything called `params` in the code you posted. That error must be coming from some other code. Anyway, I added a working example of my solution that you can run. Press `Run code snippet`

Comment: Thanks Charlie. ``` var hasEnoughPlayers = function(playerArray){
  if (playerArray.length >= 7) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}; ``` worked but I am still getting an error message ``` Cannot read property 'params' ```

Comment: @EmmanuelAni You don't need that if statement. `playerArray.length >= 7` is already either `true` or `false`, so you can just return it directly. It does the exact same thing.

Comment: @EmmanuelAni `params` is not mentioned anywhere in your code. That error comes from somewhere else so you should try to determine where it is happening and, if you can't fix it, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your doing i < (playerArray.length - 1) instead of i < (playerArray.length). Since your asking for less than and not less than or equal too, it's not gonna return true so replace i < (playerArray.length - 1) with i < (playerArray.length)